# Wifi repeater 3com 7760

Tags: wifi, 3com, repeater

I have a problem with a wifi repeater that I am configuring (3Com Wireless 7760)

Here some pictures of my installation of the device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/foRcB.jpg

According to the manual of the device, connect with a network cable and connect to the LAN, should you turn on your power button, but I don't see any lights in any of the 4 devices that I have. The devices are new and im surprised that none of the 4 work.

I found the following books, but I can not understand. I imagine that at least the power button light should be on:

www.conectavilanova.com/descargas/manuales/AP(3com)_V1_0709.pdf
www.manualowl.com/m/3Com/7760/Manual/296999

Any idea?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the pictures as inline images? Because external links tend to go dead.

Comment: i tried but i need for reputation. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`PoE` (Power over Ethernet)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) capable switch. The Netgear thing that I see there most probably is not PoE capable. You can also use a `PoE injector`, you would go from Switch -> `PoE Injector` -> `Patch Panel`

Comment: I use a PoE and power led turns on :'D http://i.imgur.com/DQWDnz6.jpg How can i detect the device in my net? I dont see any ip with port 80 on

Comment: That's something you Need to consult the documentation for the device. Often it has 192.168.0.1 or something by Default, or there is a "Management Application" which can detect and configure the device